# Custom double[] UserType with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, custom-type

I am using Hibernate 5.0.7 and PostgreSql in my application.
Furthermore I have a table which has a double[] datatype column.
To map that field with Hibernate in my entity I created a class which implements the UserType interface:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.*;

public class DoubleArrayUserType implements UserType {
    protected static final int  SQLTYPE = java.sql.Types.ARRAY;

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(final ResultSet rs, final String[] names, final SessionImplementor sessionImplementor, final Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        Array array = rs.getArray(names[0]);
        Double[] javaArray = (Double[]) array.getArray();
        return ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(javaArray);
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(final PreparedStatement statement, final Object object, final int i, final SessionImplementor sessionImplementor) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        Connection connection = statement.getConnection();

        double[] castObject = (double[]) object;
        Double[] doubles = ArrayUtils.toObject(castObject);
        Array array = connection.createArrayOf("DOUBLE", doubles);

        statement.setArray(i, array);
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble(final Serializable cached, final Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return cached;
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(final Object o) throws HibernateException {
        return o == null ? null : ((double[]) o).clone();
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(final Object o) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) o;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object x, final Object y) throws HibernateException {
        return x == null ? y == null : x.equals(y);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(final Object o) throws HibernateException {
        return o == null ? 0 : o.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(final Object original, final Object target, final Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return original;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<double[]> returnedClass() {
        return double[].class;
    }

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[] { SQLTYPE };
    }
}
```

When I try to save an entity containing a double[], the ccode fails with the following exception

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.createArrayOf(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/sql/Array;

    at com.mycompany.DoubleArrayUserType.nullSafeSet(DoubleArrayUserType.java:30)
    at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeSet(CustomType.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2598)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2883)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3386)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:560)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2963)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:61)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:485)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy141.save(Unknown Source)
```

which originates in the line `Array array = connection.createArrayOf("DOUBLE", doubles);` of my `DoubleArrayUserType` class.
It appears, that the string val `"DOUBLE"` is inappropriate, but I can't figure out why. Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I think the problem ist that the class you are calling (com.mchange.v2.c3p0.NewProxyConnection) has been compiled against older interface definition, i.e. with older JDK.

Comment: I have included c3p0 with Maven and just tried the newest version (0.9.5.2). How can such an error even be possible? Any ideas how I could fix it?

Comment: I have cloned latest master of c3p0, there is README stateting it supports JDBC 3.0 and build.properties file defining jvm.target.version=1.6. JDBC from JDK 1.7 onwards is not backwards compatible. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#incompatibilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the used c3p0 connection pool does not support JDBC 4.1 yet.

You need to use another connection pool or get c3p0 compiled on 1.7+ JDK.

Comment: So basically you are saying, that I should not/can not use c3p0 at all with the requirements I have got, until they have JDBC 4.1 support?

Comment: Yes, either that, or perhaps try to compile c3p0 with 1.7+ JDK and 1.7+ target. It is however possible that the sources need some tinkering, I have no idea how much. I would go for another connection pool.